# How to overlay multiple matplots using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What Im trying to do is; I have a few different matrices... normally I could plot them using `matplot` (and by melting to use with ggplot) but what I'm trying to achieve is to overlay the 3 matrices on one single plot.

For example, if I have create 3 different matrices like so:

```
mat <- NULL
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(i)
  mat[i] <-  list(matrix(rbinom(100,20,0.6), ncol=10))
}
```

I could normally plot each matrix separately using `matplot` (and ggplot) like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

# for example, plotting just the 2nd matrix using matplot
matplot(mat[[2]],  type = c("b"), pch=1, col = 1:10)

# Now ggplot
data <- as.data.frame(mat[[2]])
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)
# reshape to long format
plot_data <- melt(data, id.var = "id")

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = id, y = value, group = variable, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

But what I would like to do is to overlay all 3 matrices on the same plot (preferably using ggplot)... Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(mat, ~ as.data.frame(.x) %>% 
      mutate(id = row_number()), .id = 'grp') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(grp, id)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, group = grp, colour = name)) + 
     geom_line() + 
     theme_bw() +
     theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I was clear enough in my question. I will edit it to reflect what I want. Instead of having multiple separate plots using `facet_wrap`, what Im trying to do is overlay the 3 matrices onto one single plot

Comment: @Electrino then just change the 'group = 'grp'`

Comment: I just made a comment on the other answer.. maybe im missing something here... but using your method doesn't produce the same plot. For example, if I plot mat[[2]] in my example above, it doesn't appear the same as the centre panel (when using `facet_wrap`)

Comment: @Electrino your question is to create all the matrix plot in the same one and this code does that

Answer (score 2):

**Update: see comments:**
You could plot 3 plots and then arrange with `patchwork` library.

```
ibrary(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df<- map_dfr(mat, ~ as.data.frame(.x) %>% 
          mutate(id = row_number()), .id = 'grp') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(grp, id)) 


df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(grp==1)
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(grp==2)
df3 <- df %>% 
  filter(grp==3)



p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = id, y = value, colour = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = id, y = value, colour = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')


p3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = id, y = value, colour = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

library(patchwork)

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol=1,heights=c(2,2,2))
```

[image]

Maybe you meant to `facet_warp`
In essence this is the code of akrun.
Just added `facet_wrap` and removed `group = grp`

```
ibrary(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(mat, ~ as.data.frame(.x) %>% 
          mutate(id = row_number()), .id = 'grp') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(grp, id)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, colour = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ grp) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: those plots don't look correct... for example, if I plot mat[[2]] using my method above... it doesn't look like the centre plot in this `facet_wrap`... am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. Just removed `group = grp` from `ggplot aes`. Please see my edit.

Comment: And if I wanted to avoid using `facet_wrap` and overlay the 3 plots on top of each other?. when I remove the `facet_wrap` line, the plot looks weird again. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry, I don't think im being clear... Im trying to overlay the 3 plots onto a single plot... not 3 individual plots... just one plot with the 3 matrices plotted on it. Not unlike the other answer... but with the other answer, the plots look weird